# Mesh becomes transparent when pairing to armature

Tags: modeling, mesh, transparency, unity

My issue is that when I import a model into unity, parts of it are transparent.

[image]

On the left is how the mesh should be, and on the right, the mesh is transparent. I have made this model in blender and the right objects are the duplicated and mirrored versions of the left. I can convert the objects into meshes in blender, but then they no longer follow the armature. Parenting them to the armature makes them transparent again. I have tried flipping normals and recalculating normals.

Cheers

Comment: Hello, could you please share the shoe object? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Try applying scale to the meshes before exporting, it might have a negative scale unapplied and it resolves that on export to FBX. I'm willing to bet if you go into blender and apply the scale on those meshes it will suddenly "pop" inside out and then you can correct the normals.

Comment: I had the same problem. It seems this happened because I mirrored bones in Blender. Flipping normals didn't work for me, so I just rebuilt the skeleton without mirroring.